# Populating combobox from another combobox

Tags: c#

I am populating combobox from another combobox by writing code

```
<i> public void fillCombo(ComboBox cb, string query, string displayMember, string valueMember) {
        cmd=new SqlCommand(query,c.con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(d.dt3);
        cb.DataSource = d.dt3;
        cb.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        cb.ValueMember = valueMember;        
    }
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int val;
        Int32.TryParse(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
        string q = "Select * From Tehsil where DistrictID =" + val;
        fillCombo(comboBox1, q, "Tehsil_name", "TehsilID");
    } </i>
```

combobox in being populate but not filtering the data. it is repeating the combobox items. how to filter data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a View and assigning RowFilter (I'm assuming the dataset & table may be shared across other controls for binding).

Here's how I'd modify the function

```
public void fillCombo(ComboBox cb, string query, string displayMember, string valueMember, int districtID) {
    cmd=new SqlCommand(query,c.con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(d.dt3);
    var comboView = d.dt3; //Assuming d.dt3 is a DataTable, if it is dataset you will need d.dt3.Tables["table_name"] or [index]
    comboView.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("{0}={1}", "DistrictID", districtID); //This should filter the view being bound to CB.
    cb.DataSource = comboView;
    cb.DisplayMember = displayMember;
    cb.ValueMember = valueMember;        
    cb.DataBind(); //Explicit Call to Databind
}

// you will be calling it as below
fillCombo(comboBox1, q, "Tehsil_name", "TehsilID", val); //val is district ID as assigned in your comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged event handler.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void fillCombo(ComboBox cb, string query, string displayMember, string valueMember) {
    cmd=new SqlCommand(query,c.con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    d.dt3.Clear();
    sda.Fill(d.dt3);
    cb.DataSource = d.dt3;
    cb.DisplayMember = displayMember;
    cb.ValueMember = valueMember;        
}
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int val;
    Int32.TryParse(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
    string q = "Select * From Tehsil where DistrictID =" + val;
    fillCombo(comboBox1, q, "Tehsil_name", "TehsilID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that **d** is **DataSet** and **dt3** is **DataTable**. I think that you need to clear DataTable's (dt3) data before you call sda.Fill(d.dt3).

```
d.dt3.Rows.Clear();
sda.Fill(d.dt3);
```